# Getting user license in Google Apps Marketplace - Error

Tags: python, google-app-engine, error-handling, google-apps-marketplace

According to the new [Google Apps Marketplace documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/v2/reference/), in order to get the status of a user license, it should be enough to make a simple `GET` request to [https://www.googleapis.com/appsmarket/v2/userLicense/{applicationId}/{userId}?key={ApiKey}](https://www.googleapis.com/appsmarket/v2/userLicense/%7BapplicationId%7D/%7BuserId%7D?key=%7BApiKey%7D) where `applicationId` is a number, `userId` an email and `ApiKey` a string taken directly from the Google Cloud Console under `APIs -> {App name} -> Server Key -> Api Key`.
 I have also enabled the Google Apps Marketplace API in Google Cloud Console.

However, I always get the following error message:

```
{"error":
{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"authError","message":"Invalid OAuth header","locationType":"header","location":"Authorization"}],
"code":401,"message":"Invalid OAuth header"}}
```

Can you help me?

EDIT: Following Arun Nagarajan's suggestion, I tried using a scope, but it still does not work. Here is my code (in Python on Google Appengine):

```
credentials = oauth2client.appengine.AppAssertionCredentials(scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/appsmarketplace.license')
http = credentials.authorize(http=httplib2.Http())
client = apiclient.discovery.build('appsmarket', 'v2', http=http, developerKey='XXXXXXXX')
entry = client.userLicense().get(applicationId='123456', userId='some_user@email.com').execute()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use OAuth 2 with the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/appsmarketplace.license scope.

You cannot just get the license with just the server key.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it does not work for me. I still get "Invalid OAuth header" error. Besides, the scope mention returns a 404 Not found error.

Comment: The scope itself is not something you make a request to.

Can you confirm that you've created the this OAuth 2 Client ID in the same Developer Console project that you've enabled the GAM SDK? They need to be in the same project for us to verify that you are authorized to access for the user license.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I am using an OAuth2 "server api key" for a "registered app" in a project where I have enabled GAM SDK and GAM API. By the way, I used a similar code for the OAuth2 Drive API (with different parameters of course) and it works correctly.

Comment: Server API key is not sufficient for this API. You need to do the fully OAuth flow that adds in the `Authorization` header.

Comment: Where did you get that scope url from? I've been looking all over for it!